# gethostname() gives exit status -1 how do i handle this?

Tags: c++, linux

I am attempting to store the computers name in a string called computerName. When gethostname() is run the program exits and displays exit status -1. I'm trying to figure out how to handle this. Is there a way of preventing the program from exiting completely and is there a way of catching what went wrong. The documentation on gethostname() says its errors are EFAULT, EINVAL, ENAMETOOLONG and EPERM. I'm not sure how to catch any of them.

The question is not so much why the error is occurring but how to handle it.

The reason the error is occurring is because I'm running the code on an online ide which has obvious restrictions and this error doesn't occur on other machines. I have tried surrounding the code in an try and catch(...) statement but it still shows exit_status -1.

```
void GetComputerName()
  {

    char hostname[1024];
    gethostname(hostname, 1024);

    computerName = hostname;

  }

//and then outputting
std::cout << computerName << std::endl;
```

The expected result
Linux-1994    //or whatever the computers name is

Comment: "_The documentation on gethostname() says its errors are EFAULT, EINVAL, ENAMETOOLONG and EPERM. I'm not sure how to catch any of them._" The return value, of the function? You seem to be ignoring it.

Comment: First check what the function returns. If it returns a failure (i.e. `-1`) then check `errno` for what the error was. Just about any book or tutorial or example should have shown it or explained about `errno` *somehwere*.

Comment: I think i understand what your saying the documentation does say it returns 0 for success and -1 for failure so I'm guessing you cant catch those errors i mentioned before (EFAULT ect). So how would i prevent the program from exiting? Is there some way of saying if (gethostname() returns -1) {do this} rather than just terminating the application?

Comment: Sorry i didnt refresh the page to see your comment @Some programmer dude i will research now

Answer (score 1):

You can know these errors via the global variable called *errno*.

Since the errors are constants defined as macros, you can do the following:

```
if(errno == EFAULT) printf("Specific error!")
```

[Check this to get to know the constants.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a default value for `hostname` for the case that `gethostname()` is unsuccessful:

```
    char hostname[1024] = "unknown";
    gethostname(hostname, 1024);
```

However, that probably won't solve your particular issue.

> *When `gethostname()` is run the program exits and displays exit status -1*

That's not normal behavior. On failure `gethostname()` returns a non-zero code and sets `errno`, but program execution continues.

Your runtime environment probably kills any application that invokes `gethostname()`. You can't do much about it, apart from not calling `gethostname()` or switching to another online IDE which works ([live example](https://rextester.com/FTMFT28326)).

Comment: How interesting your code works in the particular ide which i use (Repl.it) but when i copy and paste your code into my function it still exits. i wounder if this has something to do with my function being in and class object.

Comment: I am such an idiot the problem is not with gethostname() but another function in my program which gets the system uptime it is what is returning exit status -1. I apologize to all of you who just wasted there time trying to fix something that wasn't broken.

Comment: The new problem is obtaining the system uptime. This code works on my linux computer but not on an online ide. Here is the code https://rextester.com/live/KWS35056 can you confirm that the "runtime environment" kills it and there is no way of handling it on an online ide.

Comment: @Caleb - the error is because `sysinfo()` fails, after which you access an uninitialized pointer. You should first check for errors and not access the pointer if the call failed.

Comment: Thank you that worked i have added the appropriate errno checks to my functions and the program now runs gracefully. Since I'm new to stack overflow I'm not sure about how to answer the question. Should i write a new answer or just mark yours as the answer?